# How to avoid buffer overflow using scanf

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[20];
    int student_num;
    char debts[1];

    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", first_name);
    printf("Enter lastname:");
    scanf("%s", last_name);
    printf("Enter six bits length student ID:");
    scanf("%d", &student_num);
    printf("Do you have debts for university [Y/N]?");
    scanf("%s", debts);

    printf("\nYour name is %s %s.\n", first_name, last_name);
    printf("Your Student ID is %d.\n", student_num);
    printf("Debts: %s.\n", debts);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

How to avoid buffer overflow in this code? I want my code to produce such an output:

```
Enter name:Enescekilokoneyasharrontannamyantoniaaquin
Enter lastname:Basenau
Enter six bits length student ID:456789
Do you have debts for university [Y/N]?YES

Your name is **Enescekilokoneyashar** (only 20 bits from name input) *Basenau*.
Your Student ID is **393299**.
Debts: **Y**.

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 36.336 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I have tried to use:

```
scanf("%19s", first_name);
```

But it does not work as I expect. I need to find some another way to validate input parameters to prevent buffer overflow attack and limit input to buffers size.

Comment: `scanf()` is a horrible function to parse input, as you're finding out.  When it fails to convert input, it leaves your input stream in an unknown state, which is really bad if it's a stream like `stdin` where you can't go back. Even more perverse, if you write a set of fields using a format string with `[f]printf()`, that same format string isn't guaranteed to be able to read that same data when used by `scanf()`.  It's usually much better to read an entire line via `fgets()` (or `getline()` if available) and parse the string yourself. You can even use `sscanf()` to replicate `scanf()`.

Comment: (cont) That also handles newlines much better than `scanf()`'s "Did I leave the newline in the buffer or not?!?" uncertainty when `scanf()` is mixed with other input-reading functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can maintain the use of `scanf` but you need to limit the size of what it can take to the size of the destination buffer, something like:

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]", first_name); //last destination buffer element is for null byte
```

Note that this specifier can parse spaces so you can take an input with more than one word.

It will, however, leave a `\n` character in the `stdin` buffer, or the remaining characters that were not parsed in case you input a larger string, so you need to clear it every time you want to parse a new input, you can make a handy function that you can call when you need such clearence, making it a pattern:

```
void clear_buffer(){
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        continue;
    }
}
```

Your `char debts[1]` buffer is also problematic, it's too small to store a string, it needs to have at least 2 characters to be able to store the null terminator:

```
char debts[2];
```

And the call will be:

```
clear_buffer();
scanf(" %1[^\n]", debts);
```

Lastly you should verify the return of `scanf`, for instance, in `scanf("%d", &student_num)`, if you input alphabetical characters instead of digits, the function will fail to parse and return 0, you can also make it parse at most 6 digits, something along the lines of:

```
clear_buffer();
if(scanf("%6d", &student_num) == 0){ // %6d limit the input to 6 digits
    //handle error
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/IndigoLovelyError)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

If you are on windows you can use scanf_s() as described in the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).
There is also an example given:

```
char s[10];
scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s));
```

Comment: How is `scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s));` any different from `scanf("%9s", s);`?  If it's because you think `scanf()` is deprecated, Microsoft is lying to you.  `scanf()` is a function any C implementation ***must*** provide - it's not "deprecated" at all.

Comment: Well he wrote that `scanf("%9s", s)` "did not work as expected" (whatever that means). I never tried scanf() because (as you said, Microsoft thinks) it's deprecated (If Microsoft is lying to me that wouldn't be the first time, i honestly didn't know). That was the reason why i suggested scanf_s because it always worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, yes, the infamous Microsoft trickery.

Comment: @Michael Read this about Microsoft's implementation of Annex K of the C standard: [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)  Note that Annex K is *optional* to begin with.  Also, Microsoft botched the implementation in ways that make fixes impossible without breaking existing code.  I'm pretty sure this dates back to the days of [Microsoft's "embrace, extend, extinguish"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) mindset, which thankfully seems to have waned quite a bit.