# String member of struct is appending other string member, both parsed with scanf

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm kinda new to C. So, I have dynamically created an array of struct and wish to take input from user and store in the array.

```
struct course{
    char code[CODE_LENGTH];
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int credits;
};
```

The second string member `name` is stored just fine.
The first string member `code` gets appended with the second string member.

The program code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define CODE_LENGTH 7
#define NAME_LENGTH 3

struct course *createList(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter no. of courses you wish to take: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    struct course *courses = (struct course*)malloc(sizeof(struct course)*n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter Course Code: ");
        scanf("%s",courses[i].code);
        printf("Enter Course name: ");
        scanf("%s",courses[i].name);
        printf("Enter no. of credits: ");
        scanf("%d",&courses[i].credits);
        printf("\n");

        printf("%s\n%s ",courses[i].code,courses[i].name);
    }
    return courses;
}
```

```
int main(){
    struct course *c = NULL;
    int credit;
    c=createList();
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter no. of courses you wish to take: 2
Enter Course Code: CS6101D
Enter Course name: DS
Enter no. of credits: 4

CS6101DDS
DS Enter Course Code:
```

If `CODE_LENGTH` is 7 how can `code` store more than that and why is it appending the other string?
Help me out!

Comment: C and C++ are different programming languages.

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `struct course *courses = (struct course*)malloc(sizeof(struct course)*n);` in C it is recommended to use `struct course *courses = malloc(n * sizeof *courses);` which is shorter and safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If `CODE_LENGTH` is 7 how can code store more than that and why is it appending the other string?*

It can't, in fact it can only store 6 characters plus the null byte, the erratic behavior of your program is the consequence of [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3).

Your code is extremely vulnerable to buffer overflow, you should never use `%s` specifier in `scanf`, like it is, its no better than `gets` and that was removed from the standard for being too dangerous and vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks, you must limit the input to the size of the destination buffer:

```
printf("Enter Course Code: "); 
scanf("%6s", courses[i].code);// %6s, 7 - 1, last element stores null byte
printf("Enter Course name: "); 
scanf("%2s", courses[i].name) //same idea
```

Note that if the input is larger than what the buffer can take, the remaining characters will remain in the `stdin` buffer and will be parsed by the next `scanf`, you may need to clear it. I just answered a question exactly about how to do that in a robust manner still using `scanf` [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369132/6865932).

---

**Off-topic:**

In

```
struct course *courses = (struct course*)malloc(sizeof(struct course)*n);
```

You should remove the cast, it's not needed and can hide allocation errors.

It's also a good practice to use the variable itself to infer the size, it keeps the code easier to maintain:

```
struct course *courses = malloc(sizeof *courses * n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably reading a string of **7** (or more?) characters, such as `CS6101D`, which will require **8** `chars` to be stored, since you will need one more `char` for the NUL terminator `'\0'`, which `scanf` will add automatically.

Hence, you code is trying to write on `courses[i].code[8]`, which has an out of bound index. This is undefined behavior in C, and can result in anything at all, including the result you got.