# Scanf function skips

Tags: c, io, scanf, user-input

In similar questions, the scanf reading a char or string skips because it takes in a new line from the input buffer after the "Enter" key is pressed for the previous scanf, but I don't think that's the issue here. This program does not skip the 2nd scanf if input1 is an integer, but it skips it for other types of inputs (double, char, string, etc.).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int input1;
    char input2[6];
    printf("Enter an integer. ");
    scanf("%d", &input1);
    printf("You chose %d\n", input1);
    
    printf("Write the word 'hello' ");
    scanf(" %s", input2);
    
    if (strcmp(input2,"hello")==0){
        printf("You wrote the word hello.\n");
    }  else {
        printf("You did not write the word hello.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Provide code where the problem occurs.

Comment: `char input2[6];` is dangerously small for unrestricted input and can suffer buffer overrun and consequent *undefined behaviour*. Suggest `scanf("%5s", input2);`

Comment: It doesn't skip the second scanf after entering a `double`. Just `printf("%s\n", input2);` to see what actually happened.

Comment: If the first input for `%d` cannot be satisfied the remaining input is left in the buffer to the scanned by the next `scanf`. So if the `double` you enter is say `1.23` then the `".23"` remains in the buffer.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`! You cause UB when `scanf()` fails and you access the uninitialized variable.

Comment: @WeatherVane That makes sense, thanks

Comment: It will be much easier to handle incorrect input (and repeat) if you input with `fgets` and extract from the string with `sscanf`. If it is incorrect input just input another string.

Comment: It's fine to use `scanf` to read simple integers, floating-point values, and (spaceless) strings.  Trying to use it for anything else, or trying to figure out what goes wrong if the user types something other than the integer or floating-point value that was expected, is a colossal waste of time and IMO not worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in code:

```
int input1 = 0; // Always initialize the var, just in case user enter EOF
                // (CTRL+D on unix) (CTRL + Z on Windows)

while (1) // Loop while invalid input
{
    printf("Enter an integer. ");

    int res = scanf("%d", &input1);
    if ((res == 1) || (res == EOF))
    {
        break; // Correct input or aborted via EOF
    }
    int c;
    // Flush stdin on invalid input
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
printf("You chose %d\n", input1);
```

Also, take a look to [How to avoid buffer overflow using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368589/how-to-avoid-buffer-overflow-using-scanf)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write "%*c" after your %c or %s or %d ?
Something like this : scanf("%s%*c", input1);